# Parent array keys taking precedence

Tags: php, arrays

My session array looks like the following:

```
$_SESSION => array(
    "acc"=>array(
        "name"=>"Account name",
        "id"=>1,
        ...
    ),
    "name"=>"User name",
    ...
);
```

**To clarify, please note** that this is just to show the format. I am not actually setting `$_SESSION` to a new array. For that code, please see the end of the question.

If I dump the `$_SESSION,` I get just what I expect; however, if I try to reference one of the `"acc"` variables that has the a key that is used in the parent session array, it will give me the result stored in the session array.

For instance

```
$_SESSION["acc"]["name"]
```

This returns "User name", when it should return "Account name".

Why is this?

---

If I set the acc variable key to something else, like `aname`, e.g.

```
$_SESSION["acc"]["aname"]
```

This returns "Account name" like it should.

---

#### Session creation code:

```
session_start();

$acc = array(
    "id"=>$accid,
    "sub"=>$sub,
    "name"=>$name,
    "exp"=>$exp
);

$_SESSION["acc"] = $acc;
$_SESSION["admin"] = $admin;
$_SESSION["name"] = "$fname $lname";
$_SESSION["uid"] = $uid;
```

Comment: Works for me. http://3v4l.org/25OM0

Comment: Your posted code is correct. Maybe that's some PHP bug? but I doubt. What version of PHP are you using? Are you sure you have not accidentaly mixed $name, $fname and $lname variables? :)

Comment: How is `$name` initialized? You're not doing something odd like `$name = &$_SESSION['name']` above the quoted code?

Comment: That is the exact code, pasted from my PHP file, including the call to the variable as posted above. $name is set by mysqli: `$stmt->bind_result(..., $name, ...);`

Comment: Have you got register globals turned on? See the warnings documented at, http://us3.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

Comment: Hmm...This appears to be a bug. I changed the variable keys and it worked just fine. Undid my changes, still works...Re-did changes...works, undid, doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Because `$_SESSION` is already an array when you write `$_SESSION = array (...`. You created array of array.

Comment: This was just an example. I'm not *actually* setting the array that way (but that shouldn't matter anyway...); I'm actually doing `$_SESSION["acc"] = array(...)`; I know that it works because if I dump the array, it has the proper contents.

Comment: Clear your session or you can use normal array to test this piece of code

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug. After messing around with key names, I found that after changing the key names and undoing my changes to make the key names the same again, it worked, but after doing it again, it didn't.

Comment: Similar, thought not identical, report of a bug when using bind_result and session vars: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php#98630

Comment: @faintsignal Very interesting. I guess I'll just go the safe way and use different variable names.